# div from gridview - onclick width changing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

can somebody tell me following code in asp.net c# codebehind.

If i click and select any row in gridview ---> change CSS-DIV width, which runat server.

And where do i have to paste it? i tryed few things, but it doesnt matter where i code it, the width changes on page_load instead of "on gridview click"

Generally i need it for that scheme http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/ChangeWidth.1412455799.jpg
 Thanks for any advises!

Comment: try at GridView Selected Index change event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: <div ID="GridViewDiv" runat ="server"> The problem is that i have to change only CSS div, if i change only gridview CCSstyle, this div will anyway having 100% width on my page, and detailsview stays below (

Comment: show code behind of Edit button click

Comment: protected void gvTimeSheet_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {     
      e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvTimeSheet, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);  
      Label lblqy = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1");
      decimal qty = 0;
      if (lblqy.Text.Length > 0)
      qty = Convert.ToDecimal(lblqy.Text.Replace(",", ".")); 
      total = total + qty; 
      totaleuro = total * 8; 
    }

Comment: THis one is like a button to change in Detailsview edit    e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvTimeSheet, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);

Comment: `Select$` ?? paste that Hyperlink Control.aspx

Comment: it should be like this `a.HRef = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvTimeSheet, anchor_ID.ToString());`

Comment: here is full code, found a website ti share it =) http://codepad.org/DT3rQ7hK

Comment: and aspx code http://codepad.org/GD498Al3

Comment: nono) it works so, if i click on any gridview row, i get my detailsview visible + edit mode for that RoW. Because of Databound();

Comment: posted answer try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{

dvtimeSheet.Visible = false;
//hide your details view
}
```

Add On `OnSelectedIndexChanging` Event to GridView

```
 OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvTimeSheet_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
```

and Use In Code Behind

```
 protected void gvTimeSheet_OnSelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvTimeSheet.Visible = false;
        dvtimeSheet.Visible = true;
        dvtimeSheet.Style.Add("left", "120px");
        dvtimeSheet.Style.Add("height", "260px");
        dvtimeSheet.Style.Add("width", "120px");
        dvtimeSheet.Style.Add("position", "absolute");
//same you can do with your div(making true/false or adding style)
        }
```

**Note:** Use `Update Panels` with `EnableEventValidation="false"` in `Page Directives`
and Use Firebug for mozilla to adding style and alignments

**EDIT:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Ah Thanks, I already tryed the same methode, but! i found my problem why i did't do it to work. ANd this is: My DIV calls FormViewDiv, but if i set an attrubure runat="server" it becomes as mainContent_FormViewDiv and this name of DIV, doesnt not exist in Code behind, I always get this error. Do u have any ideas how to fix it?))

Comment: But anyway thanks, you helped a lot. Now I know where i have to looking for!=)